# HTTP1.1のパイプライン処理でサーバーがリクエストをどのくらい待てばいいか？

Tags: http

HTTP1.1のサーバーサイドの実装をしています。
パイプライン処理はGETやHEADが連続でくるということですが、パイプライン開始のトリガーが(私が調べた限り)ないため、最初のGETを受け取った後に次に来るGET(or HEAD)の対処が難しいと考えています。

GET /A.html\r\n
\r\n
GET /B.html\r\n
\r\n
GET /C.html\r\n
\r\n

上記の場合、
最初に「GET /A.html」を受け取っているので、サーバーはそのコンテンツを返すべきですが、
もしこれが上記のようにパイプラインなら、二つ目の「GET B.html」が来る可能性があるのでrecv()で待機に入る必要があります。ですが、このrecv()はいつまでやるべきでしょうか？
タイムアウトするまでだとしても、1秒とか待機していてはロスですし、短すぎてもまだクライアントサイドがデータ送信中の可能性があります。もしくは二つ目のGETが来ない可能性もあります。

あと、そもそものお話ですが、HTTP1.1のパイプラインは一般的によく使われているのでしょうか？
最近のブラウザとサーバーでは実装されているようですが、
ブラウザはデフォルトでパイプラインでコンテンツを取得しにいくのか、滅多にこのような取得方法は行われないのか、ご存じの方がいらしたら教えていただけると助かります。

(最初の1枚目のコンテンツはリクエストとレスポンスが1対1で、その中身をパイプラインで取得しにいく、という感じだと想像しています)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 Pipelining は、最初にリクエストを複数受け取り、受け取った順番(FIFO)でレスポンスを送り返すだけの機能です。実装するだけなら簡単かもしれません。これは確か、サーバサイドコンテンツ生成処理の並列化が目的の機能だったと思います。

きちんと調べきってはいないのですが、最近の状況を知らなかったので、この機会に少し調べてみました。

### ■ HTTP Pipelining: どのタイミングで切断するか

W3C の [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html) 仕様に以下のような言及がありました。

> **8.1.4 Practical Considerations**
>
> Servers will usually have some time-out value beyond which they will no longer maintain an inactive connection. Proxy servers might make this a higher value since it is likely that the client will be making more connections through the same server. The use of persistent connections places no requirements on the length (or existence) of this time-out for either the client or the server.
> ...
> A client, server, or proxy MAY close the transport connection at any time. For example, a client might have started to send a new request at the same time that the server has decided to close the "idle" connection. From the server's point of view, the connection is being closed while it was idle, but from the client's point of view, a request is in progress.
> ...
> Servers SHOULD always respond to at least one request per connection, if at all possible. Servers SHOULD NOT close a connection in the middle of transmitting a response, unless a network or client failure is suspected.
> ...

抜粋すると「サーバはいつ切断してもよいが、レスポンスを返している途中で接続を切るべきではない」「クライアントはサーバに接続を切られた場合に常に備えるべきだ」ということらしい。ここから、、

- サーバは、クライアントから受け取った未解決のリクエストを無視して切断して良い
- サーバによる切断のタイミングは、レスポンス送信中より、送り切った時点が良い

と読めます。

### ■ HTTP Pipelining: 接続がタイムアウトをするべき時間

サーバ用の具体的なタイムアウト値は調べきりませんでした。決まっていないと思います。極端な話、最後のレスポンスを送り切ったら、即切りしてよいのではないでしょうか。どのぐらいコネクションを維持するかどうかは、 Keep-Alive 機能の領分だと理解しています。 (Apache のKeep-Alive の Timeout デフォルト値は、 5-15 秒)

クライアントサイドの Firefox を調べたところ、config に "[network.http.pipelining](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.pipelining).read-timeout" があり、デフォルト 30 秒と設定されていました。しかしコメントに、[`The amount of time a pipelined transaction is allowed to wait before being canceled and retried in a non-pipeline connection`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpHandler.cpp#) とあり、サーバのタイムアウトとはリンクしなさそうでした。（ここで面白かったのは、 pipelining の実装が、[サーバの種類によって機能の On/Off を切り替えるようなもの](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/http/nsHttpConnection.cpp#806)になっていたことです。）

### ■ HTTP Pipelining をサポートする ブラウザ

#### Desktop Browsers

- **Opera**:
  [バージョン 4](http://www.operasoftware.com/press/releases/desktop/opera-4.0-upgrades-file-exchange-includes-http-1.1) からフルサポート。
- **Chrome**:
  サポートしない。バージョン [17 で実験機能として導入](https://web.archive.org/web/20130125055603/http://www.conceivablytech.com/9688/products/google-introduces-http-pipelining-in-chrome-17)、26 で除去された。 ([#8991](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8991) /[#364557](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364557))
- **Firefox**:
  サポートするが、デフォルト無効になっている。 ([#2654354](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=264354))
- **Safari**:
  サポートしない。
- **Internet Explorer**:
  サポートしない。

#### Mobile Browsers

モバイルデバイスでは以下の３つ

- **Mobile Opera**:
  フルサポート。
- **Mobile Safari**
  iOS 5 から[サポートしてるぽい](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15556783/safari-sends-two-http-req-same-time-socket/25751109#25751109)
- **Android Browser**:
  少なくとも 2.x からサポートがある

#### Pipelining サポートのあるブラウザのシェア

以上のサポート具合から、

- **Desktop Browser**: [2% 程](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-ww-monthly-201406-201412)
- **Mobile Browser** : [50% 程](http://gs.statcounter.com/#mobile_browser-ww-monthly-201406-201412)

のブラウザで、 HTTP/1.1 Pipelining が使えていることになります。

### ■ 雑感

Pipelining は、モバイル機器を対象にすれば意味がある機能です。パフォーマンスが理論上は速くなるはずだったのに、実際は期待したほど速くならず、バギーなサーバの存在から、疎まれ、壊れ仕様のような扱いになっています。んで、反省は、 SPDY, HTTP/2.0 に生かされているようです。

---

以下、参考サイト:

- [Status of HTTP Pipelining in Chromium](https://insouciant.org/tech/status-of-http-pipelining-in-chromium/)
- [Making HTTP Pipelining Usable on the Open Web](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-pipeline-01)
- [Network Performance Effects of HTTP/1.1, CSS1, and PNG](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Performance/Pipeline.html)
- [HTTP Pipelining – Big in Mobile](http://www.guypo.com/http-pipelining-big-in-mobile/)
- [HTTP pipelining - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining)
- [HTTP Pipelining is a Hit and Miss](https://www.subbu.org/blog/2012/07/http-pipelining-hit-and-miss)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
非常に有益な情報をいただき、感謝いたします。
とりあえずで、非同期で現時点でクライアントから取得できているリクエストのまとまりに対してレスポンスをまとめて返す。レスポンスを一通り返し終えたあるタイミングで数秒間リクエストがなければ切る。という実装で良さそうな気がしています。

Internet Explorer:はサポートしないとのことですが、IE8以降は実装されているとの情報もありました。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Belinda/20080414/1208183066
実際に連続で送られるパケットもこちらで確認できています(私自身ではなく私の知人ですが)。

Comment: いえ、興味が先走って、完全に回答できなくて申し訳ない感じです。 IE によるサポートの有無は、[Wikipediaの記事](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining#Implementation_in_web_servers)の`Internet Explorer 8 does not pipeline requests`の記述と、[MicrosoftサポートのChatログ](http://wayback.archive.org/web/*/http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/expertzone/chats/transcripts/08_0814_ez_ie8.mspx) で Expert が pipelining を dis っている様子から判断しました。検索してみてもサポートの有無を明確に述べた情報は少ないです。実際試行してみて、レスポンスを待たない 複数 URL への連続要求がくるならば、サポートしてるのでしょうね。

Comment: 「数‌​秒間リクエストがなければ切る」が引っかかります。HTTP Pipeliningとは別にHTTP Persistent Connectionがあります。ユーザーは閲覧中にクリックすれば新たなリクエストが発生する可能性が高く、その際に再接続していては効率が悪いため、クライアント・サーバー双方は許容できる範囲でコネクションを維持します。HTTP Pipeliningはその発展形に過ぎません。
ちなみにRFC2616よりRFC7230が適切です。
「バギーなサーバ」というのは実装するとわかりますが、先行するレスポンスを追い越して後続するレスポンスを返してしまい、コンテンツが混ざったり入れ替わったりすることが原因です。

Comment: ありゃ、RFC2616 は obsolute ですねこれは頭古い。該当箇所へのリンク→[RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.2)([日本語訳](http://www.hcn.zaq.ne.jp/___/WEB/RFC7230-ja.html#section-6.3.2))。
HTTP/1.1 は、 Keep-Alive が暗黙デフォルトで、それが HTTP Persistent Connection として扱われているということで理解しています。 Http Pipelining は、Persistent Connection 機能を必須としていますが、Apacheの設定がどうなっているのか見るときは、 KeepAlive 系の項目を見るしかない気がします。昔々試したときはなにもリクエストしないと300秒、Keep-Alive リクエストするとその後15秒ぐらいで閉じた記憶。同時接続数でも切断動作変わってくる筈なのでまじめにまねようとすると実装者大変かも。

Comment: >sayuriさん
ありがとうございます。
クライアント・サ‌​ーバー双方は許容できる範囲でコネクションを維持する点について、認識しています。自分の実装では数秒間に設定してみるという意味です。問題あれば調整するつもりです。

Answer (score 1):

HTTPパイプラインの前提として非同期I/Oがあるはずです。つまり

- クライアントからのリクエストのrecv()
- ディスクからのファイルのread()
- クライアントへのレスポンスのsend()

それぞれの完了を待つのではなく、read()やsend()中に、それらの結果に影響されない次のrecv()が行えるはずです。（説明の簡単化のためにsendfile()は除外してます。）
ですので、「このrecv()はいつまでやるべきでしょうか？」という質問自体おかしなものに感じます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
そもそも同期処理で考えているのが間違いだということが分かりました。